# Retain countdown timer value when switching between view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, timer, viewcontroller, countdown

I'm working on a trip countdown app that also has weather forecast built in.

Things are working pretty well, but when I switch from countdown timer to weather forecast, then come back, the countdown timer is reset.

Here's my countdown view controller code:

```
import UIKit

class CountdownVC: UIViewController {

    var timer = Timer()

    let userCalendar = Calendar.current
    let requestedComponent: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.day,.hour,.minute,.second]
    var departureDateTime: Date?

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    let images = [
        UIImage(named: "MK.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "SSE1.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "TofT.png"),
        UIImage(named: "TofL1.png")!]
    var index = 0
    let animationDuration: TimeInterval = 0.25
    let switchingInterval: TimeInterval = 15

    func animateImageView()
    {
        CATransaction.begin()

        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(animationDuration)
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + self.switchingInterval) {
                self.animateImageView()
            }
        }

        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.type = kCATransitionFade
        imageView.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
        imageView.image = images[index]
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.alpha = 0.5

        CATransaction.commit()

        index = index < images.count - 1 ? index + 1 : 0
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var departureDateTimePicker: UIDatePicker!

    @IBAction func departureDateTimePicker(_ sender: Any) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss"
        departureDateTimePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handler), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var selectDepartureDateTimeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var daysLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var hoursLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var minutesLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondsLabel: UILabel!


    func handler(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss"
        let departureDateTimeString = dateFormatter.string(from: departureDateTimePicker.date)
        departureDateTime = dateFormatter.date(from: departureDateTimeString)
    }

    func printTime() {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss"
        let startTime = Date()
        let endTime = departureDateTime
        let timeDifference = userCalendar.dateComponents(requestedComponent, from: startTime, to: endTime!)
        let startTimeDouble: Double = startTime.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
        var endTimeDouble: Double?
        endTimeDouble = (endTime?.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
        if endTimeDouble! > startTimeDouble {
            daysLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.day!) Days"
            hoursLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.hour!) Hours"
            minutesLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.minute!) Minutes"
            secondsLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.second!) Seconds"

        } else {
            timer.invalidate()
            daysLabel.text = ""
            hoursLabel.text = ""
            minutesLabel.text = ""
            secondsLabel.text = ""
        }
    }

    func runTimer() {
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(printTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timer.fire()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var startBtn: UIButton!

    @IBAction func startBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        handler(sender: departureDateTimePicker)
        printTime()
        runTimer()
        selectDepartureDateTimeLabel.text = "Time to departure"
        departureDateTimePicker.isHidden = true
        startBtn.isHidden = true
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var resetBtn: UIButton!

    @IBAction func resetBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        timer.invalidate()
        selectDepartureDateTimeLabel.text = "Select departure date & time"
        departureDateTimePicker.isHidden = false
        startBtn.isHidden = false
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss"
        let startTime = Date()
        let endTime = startTime
        let timeDifference = userCalendar.dateComponents(requestedComponent, from: startTime, to: endTime)
        daysLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.day!) Days"
        hoursLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.hour!) Hours"
        minutesLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.minute!) Minutes"
        secondsLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.second!) Seconds"
    }

    @IBAction func goToWeatherBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToWeatherVC", sender: self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageView.image = images[index+1]
        animateImageView()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The timer is reset"?

Comment: How are you switching between controllers? Are you using a segue both directions?

Comment: The departure date and time value is reset to the current date and time, so the labels showing days, hours, minutes, and seconds to go are all reset to 0.

Comment: I have a button on each view controller that triggers a segue to the other view controller.

Comment: A segue always creates a new destination VC unless you use an *unwind segue*.  Is CountDownVC the first or the second VC?

Comment: Second View controller

Comment: You need to show the code that handles the transition/segue between the view controllers. If you're using segues in both directions that is your problem. I suggest creating your second view controller using `instantiateViewController(identifier:)` and then either pushing it onto a navigation controller (if you have one) or presenting it modally. Then pop/dismiss the second view controller and the first view controller will still be there and it's timer property will still be  intact.

Comment: Why tie the timer code to a view controller if it needs to be globally accessible?

Comment: using unwindsegue worked. thanks a bunch everyone! I really appreciate how helpful all of you are. I hope to develop my skills enough to where I can help others at some point.